# host native PHP project on Vercel

Tags: php, vercel

I have a simple native PHP project and I want to host it on Vercel, but I don't know what to write in the vercel.json file
This is my project structure
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkzAx.png)

It simply contains index.php file => next to it user.php file => and next to CSS folder contains css files => and next to it JS folder contains javascript files.
What should the vercel.json file look like now?

AND I would like my project link to be like this : "example.vercel.app"
NOT like this "example.vercel.app/api"

**Is this possible ?**

I tried this code and it works, but the CSS and JS files doesn't work.

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    { "src": "index.php", "use": "vercel-php@0.6.0" },
    { "src": "user.php", "use": "vercel-php@0.6.0" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [See this](https://github.com/vercel-community/php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first to understand php-runtime for vercel please visit https://github.com/wis-aerrajiy/php-vercel

in the config file vercel.json you need to add all routes of your project :
for example if you have index.php in api file /api/index.php when you want to visit the index you should browser domain.vercel.app not domain.vercel.app/api
to do that lets add our first route to the config

```
{
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/(.*)",  "dest": "/api/index.php" }
  ]
}
```

in this why each time you request this home / the server will serve the index, you can add more routes of each page, and you need to add the routes of css and js files

```
{
  "functions": {
    "api/**/*.php": {
      "runtime": "vercel-php@0.5.2"
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/(.*)",  "dest": "/api/index.php" },
    { "src": "/css/style.css", "dest": "/css/style.css" },
    { "src": "/js/script.js", "dest": "/js/script.js" }]
}
```

in this why your site should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

To host php website on vercel you need to put all your php code inside api folder and create a vercel.json file in the root folder and add the below code to the vercel.json file

```
{
    "functions": {
        "api/**/*.php": { runtime: "vercel-php@0.6.0" },
    },
    "routes": [
        { src: "/(.*)", dest: "/api/index.php" }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer instead of linking to external ressources, especially if you want to promote your own services